# What race/class combinations would you like to see in pregenerated characters?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, gm-preparation

I am running a one shot for the local gaming association and am making pre-generated level one characters for people to use.

So what Race/class combinations would work best in a group of pregenerated characters, in terms of balance and flavour. I'm making like 25 of them so lots of room.

Comment: That's kind of a wide-open question, I think? I'm not sure if it's going to produce more than a list of favorite class/race types. Is there any way you can focus it more? Is this going to be for beginners, people who've played a lot of older editions, anything like that?

Comment: Still don't know who i'm going to get playing, its an open sign up. Chacnes are people who play in associations are a bit more advanced than the average newb (but no guaranties) I'm okay with a list of favorites, thats kinda what I was going for.

Answer (score 9):

When looking for race/class combinations, especially for pregens, the main 4e theme I have is: make sure the racial stats match up with at least one primary or secondary.

Given that each character will be built with point-buy, they should all end up with +4 or +5 in their primary stat, depending on race.

Have 3-4 deadly-dull stereotypes for the munchkins (literally, young power gamers) in the crowd. I know I certainly wasn't aware of stereotypes at that stage of my life.

In points of light, avoid using monster races for a one-shot, it's too easy to have group-conflicts of "you're not acting right."

So, with all of that said, looking at this purely from a "what's the most interesting build?" We turn to our friend the charOp boards and I'll just suggest interesting combos for each class.

For a con game, just take all the light blue first level options for the respective build. It makes it less likely to have a dud character. Give everyone foo expertise for free because hitting more often is fun (and it is a math fix. Keep an eye on the monsters you're using and try to favour the MM3, but that's a topic for another question)

- Defenders

  - [Githzerai Shardmind](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/22464381/Enders_Game_-_the_Battlemind_Handbook) Battle resilience
  - [Half-Orc Tempest Fighter](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/24861409/Harder_than_a_Rock%3a_The_Fighters_Handbook) MC Rogue
  - Human Essentials Fighter (of the more defendery type)
  - [Changeling Paladin](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19649038/Pillars_of_Faith_and_Facestabs_The_Paladins_Handbook) (Charisma/wisdom focused) of trickster goddess
  - [Ambitious Eladrin Shielding Swordmage](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/22198629/Masters_of_Blade_Magic%3a_A_Swordmage_Handbook) (Nod to GiTP)
  - [Earthstrength Dwarf Warden](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/23061901/A_Rock_and_A_Hard_Place%3a_A_Warden_Handbook)
- Strikers

  - [Deva Retribution Avenger](http://community.wizards.com/charop/wiki/Avenger%27s_Handbook)
  - [Warforged Charging Rageblood Barbarian](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/25175217/Appetite_for_Destruction%3a_The_Barbarians_Handbook)
  - [Elf Centered Monk](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/25065021/No_Paper_Tigers!!!!%3a_The_Monk_Handbook)
  - Crossbow Dwarf Essentials Ranger (if it's dropped)
  - [Drow Two-weapon Ranger](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/22426033/Thrill_of_the_Hunt%3a_The_Rangers_Handbook) (Extra points if you name him "Drizzle" or some other punny name that most won't get. Non-optimal, but caters to the kiddies.)
  - Halfling Essentials rogue
  - [Thri-Kreen Brutal Scoundrel Rogue](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/22953353/Dirty_Deeds..._Done_Dirt_Cheap%3a_The_Rogues_Handbook) (with 4 daggers!)
  - [Dragonborn Dragon Sorcerer](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/23234225/Ultimate_Power%3a_The_Sorcerers_Handbook?pg=1)
  - [Tiefling Infernal Warlock](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19648994/The_Power_of_the_Dark_Side_The_Warlocks_Handbook) (Make sure to use the Dragon 386 powers)
- Leaders

  - [Kalashtar Ardent](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/25291705/Ardent_Admiration%3a_An_Ardent_Handbook%3a) (Give them the group-telepathy feat and call it a chat room. Very fun.)
  - [Shardmind Artificer](http://community.wizards.com/wiki/Dnd%3aArtificer_Handbook)
  - [Gnome Cunning Bard](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/21106285/Cruel_Lullabies_The_Bard_Handbook) (Prescient is probably better for a con, but wis/cha race support is a bit harsh.)
  - Human Essentials Warpriest
  - [Elf bow cleric, just to be odd.]
  - Human Pacifist Cleric
  - [Minotaur Wrathful Runepriest](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/22931733/Runes_of_Power%3a_A_Runepriest_Handbook)
  - [Razorclaw Shifter Watcher Shaman](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/21836709/Spirited_Away_A_Shaman_Handbook)
  - [Gensai Tactical Warlord](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/22579049/Chasing_Glory%3a_The_Warlords_Handbook)
- Controllers

  - [Wilden Guardian Druid](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19648618/Heart_of_the_Wild_A_Druid_Handbook)
  - [Deva Wrath Invoker](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/22200121/The_Whole_Duty_of_Man_-_A_guide_to_Invokers)
  - [Gnome Telepath Psion](http://community.wizards.com/wiki/Dnd%3aCharOp/Controllers/Psion/Handbook)
  - [Elf Bloodbond Seeker](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/22927725/Follow_My_Way_-_A_Seekers_Guide)
  - Tiefling Pyromancer Mage
  - [Human Tome of Readiness Wizard](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/25095865/The_Power_of_Knowledge_-_The_Wizards_Handbook)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Jadasc. I'll eventually learn to spellcheck...

Answer (score 5):

Party composition can make or break a one-shot adventure. Assets needed for resolution of combats and non-combat problems may be absent if you leave the choice up to players, resulting either in an insoluble/unwinnable scenario or demanding too much of (and possibility of wrong choices by) the game master.

Better bet: Design the characters, and *then* design the adventure specifically for them.

(I've written more than 30 rounds of large-size tournaments by this method.)

Comment: An advantage to this approach is that character-selection is quick: "Who wants to be the Dwarven Alchemist? The Elven Wizard? Okay, that leaves the Human Noble and the Halfling Spymaster. Picked? Great, let's go!"

Comment: I'm not gonna say your suggestions can't work, but is completely not what I'm wanting for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

All I've got to say is don't forget about the PC race writeups in the monster manuals (well, 1 and 2, anyway).  You've got more options than just those in the PHBs and setting books.

Comment: I agree, but it's generally not worth the effort to add those in for con pre-gens. Monster races are tricky to RP at the best of times. For people who aren't familiar with the setting, everyone will go with stereotyping. Thats why my recommendations are so... vanilla.

Comment: Yeah, probably a good point for a con situation.  But some monster races are perfectly easy to roleplay.  I suspect more people would know what to do with a goblin than a shardmind, for example.